# Auto increment in vb.net

Tags: excel, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, excel-2013

I am using visual studio 2013. I created a windows application form in visual basic and using that I am entering data in excel. 
I wrote a code to auto-increment a unique number which needs to appear as soon as form loads. But instead of appearing at that time, when i enter first data through form in excel, then it shows me the number.
The number should contain month today's date and then 01,02..and should reset back to 01 the next day. Eg: 101001 (month-10,date-10,number-01), 101002,101003... and then tomorrow it should show 101101
This is my code

```
 Private Sub Form1_Activated(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Activated
    Dim t As String = Format(Today, "MMdd")
    Dim d As Excel.Range
    'Add 1 to the counter if the day is still the same,
    d = xlWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")
    If d.Value = Today Then
        d.Offset(1, 0).Value = d.Offset(1, 0).Value + 1
    Else
        d.Value = Today
        d.Offset(1, 0).Value = 1
    End If
    If d.Offset(1, 0).Value < 10 Then
        Me.txtQuote.Text = t & "0" & d.Offset(1, 0).Value
    Else
        Me.txtQuote.Text = t & d.Offset(1, 0).Value
    End If

End Sub
```

How do I get the required number? And where should i place the code so that as soon as form loads the number should appear in textbox

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Have you tried using the Load event rather than Activated?

Comment: How do I get the required number? And where should i place the code so that as soon as form loads the number should appear in textbox

Comment: hi @DoctorMick I tried the Load event but even that doesn't work

Comment: Numbers with dates are neither autoincrementing nor numbers. They are a specific string converted to a number. The code doesn't deal with numbers anyway, it's all string manipulation

Comment: ya @PanagiotisKanavos i understand that. So what should I do ?

Comment: Are you saying that unless you place a value inside the Spreadsheet then `Me.txtQuote.Text` is empty?

Step through your code and compare both scenarios so you can try and understand what is going on.

Put a breakpoint here `If d.Offset(1, 0).Value < 10 Then`

Tell us what `d.Offset(1, 0).Value` is when data is entered inside the Spreadsheet compared with when data is not entered in the Spreadsheet.

I would also place the code inside a `Try Catch` statement as it could be throwing an exception without you knowing.

Comment: Hi @Jinx88909 I am not able to understand this. I am new to this. Sorry for  the inconvenience. I added a msgbox and it shows the value goes on incrementing until i close the excel.

Comment: Sorry I'm lost now as to what the actual issue is. Have a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx on how to debug your code and place breakpoints etc. Without knowing exactly what you're doing it's going to be difficult to provide an accurate answer.

Comment: I'll check that. Sorry to confuse you @Jinx88909
Mainly what I am trying to do is there should be aunique number in the textbox as soon as it opens and when submit is clicked then it should auto-increment. The next day it should reset back to 01.

Comment: If you've made a user control, you wont be able to use it in Excel unless you put it in a custom task pane.